# optimizing ansible playbook to overcome redundant hardcoding for multiple clients

Tags: ansible

I'm writing ansible-playbook for my new clients, where I have to copy a set of existing code to just replace new clients which resulting in redundancy.

I tried with Ansible lookup plugin with two variables(client_name,client_id) but it doesn't suit my problem

```
 - name: delete existing {{client_name}} deployment
   file: path=/opt/tomcat2/webapps/{{client_name}} state=absent

 - name: {{client_name}} dir create
   file: path=/opt/tomcat2/webapps/{{client_name}} state=directory   mode=0755

 - name: {{client_name}} deploy
   command: jar -xf /tmp/idp.war chdir=/opt/tomcat2/webapps/{{client_name}}
   sudo: True

 - name: template task-config.xml
   template: src=../roles/u4ia/templates/{{client_id}}task-config.xml dest=/opt/tomcat2/webapps/{{client_name}}/WEB-INF/classes/task-config.xml
```

whenever I need a new client, I shouldn't hardcode client names&id's by copying an existing snippet of code. I should have some variables so that simply I can add only once.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to put all the tasks into a separate file and to put variables into a specific dictionary. For example

```
$ cat update-clients.yml
 - name: delete existing {{ mlv.client_name }} deployment
   file: path=/opt/tomcat2/webapps/{{ mlv.client_name }} state=absent
 ...
```

Create a dictionary with the variables. For example

```
clients_update:
  - client_name: 'client-A'
    client_id: '007'
  - client_name: 'client-B'
    client_id: '008'
  - client_name: 'client-C'
    client_id: '009'
```

And loop *include_tasks*

```
- include_tasks: update-clients.yml
  loop: "{{ clients_update }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: mlv
```

Note. This solution is not idempotent. The apps will be deleted and created repeateadly. It would be good to add a condition to the loop and update only if needed.